# Hibernate One-to-One, When inserting, Why FK is null

Tags: java, hibernate

When I run this code, it is running with out error. But When I check the values, as you can see, In the "Tbl_InstructorDetail" table the parentId is null
can anyone help.
thank you.

This is my Entities and my main class with table relation
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qXpa2.png)

this is my tables from my database

```
create table Tbl_Instructor
(
    uuid  int identity
        constraint Pk_Tbl_Instructor_uuid
            primary key,
    Title nvarchar(50)
)

create table Tbl_InstructorDetail
(
    uuid       int identity
        constraint Pk_Tbl_InstructorDetail_uuid
            primary key,
    Created_By nvarchar(50),
    parentId   int
        constraint Fk_Tbl_InstructorDetail_Tbl_Instructor
            references Tbl_Instructor
)
```

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "Tbl_InstructorDetail", schema = "dbo", catalog = "OJT_2021_KST")
public class TblInstructorDetailEntity {
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Id
    @Column(name = "uuid", nullable = false)
    private int uuid;
    @Basic
    @Column(name = "Created_By", nullable = true, length = 50)
    private String createdBy;
    @Basic
    @Column(name = "parentId", nullable = true,insertable = false,updatable = false)
    private Integer parentId;

    @OneToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "parentId",referencedColumnName="uuid")
    private TblInstructorEntity instructorEntity;
```

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "Tbl_Instructor", schema = "dbo", catalog = "OJT_2021_KST")
public class TblInstructorEntity {
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Id
    @Column(name = "uuid", nullable = false)
    private int uuid;
    @Basic
    @Column(name = "Title", nullable = true, length = 50)
    private String title;

    @OneToOne(mappedBy="instructorEntity",cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private TblInstructorDetailEntity detailEntity;
```

`Main class`

```
            TblInstructorEntity instructor = new TblInstructorEntity();
            instructor.setTitle("This is a Test");

            TblInstructorDetailEntity detail = new TblInstructorDetailEntity();
            detail.setCreatedBy("Kyle");

            instructor.setDetailEntity(detail);

            session.getTransaction().begin();
            session.save(instructor);
            session.getTransaction().commit();
```

Comment: You have to up vote the answer if it is helpfull

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to add `parentId` in `TblInstructorDetailEntity` because it's referenced from `TblInstructorEntity`. In main class foreign key pass null because you can take a reference to the parent table before save parent table.

Here down is modified code:

**Entity**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "Tbl_InstructorDetail", schema = "dbo", catalog = "OJT_2021_KST")
public class TblInstructorDetailEntity {
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Id
    @Column(name = "uuid", nullable = false)
    private int uuid;
    @Basic
    @Column(name = "Created_By", nullable = true, length = 50)
    private String createdBy;
    
    // remove parentId column because it is foreign key

    @OneToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "parentId",referencedColumnName="uuid")
    private TblInstructorEntity instructorEntity;

    // getter setter
}

@Entity
@Table(name = "Tbl_Instructor", schema = "dbo", catalog = "OJT_2021_KST")
public class TblInstructorEntity {
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Id
    @Column(name = "uuid", nullable = false)
    private int uuid;
    @Basic
    @Column(name = "Title", nullable = true, length = 50)
    private String title;

    @OneToOne(mappedBy="instructorEntity",cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private TblInstructorDetailEntity detailEntity;

    // getter setter
}
```

**Main**

```
Session session = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().openSession();
session.beginTransaction();

TblInstructorEntity instructor = new TblInstructorEntity();
instructor.setTitle("This is a Test");

TblInstructorDetailEntity detail = new TblInstructorDetailEntity();
detail.setCreatedBy("Kyle");

session.save(instructor); // Save parent entity

detail.setInstructorEntity(instructor); // Reference from parent entity

session.save(detail); // Save child entity

session.getTransaction().commit();
HibernateUtil.shutdown();
```

Comment: Thank you, this problem has been hunting me for days. Finally get it done.Thanks a lot. By the way for one-to-many and many-to-one,  basically is the same thing right?

Comment: Sorry for that, I need 3 more reputation.  when i get 3 more reputation i will upvote your answer i promise.